# how to do spring-data validation

Tags: validation, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I was reading this article http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler , and I decided to use annotated handler method.

This guide is missing something: How can I validate? Asserting or throwing exceptions or somehow with magic annotations (as everything with Java).

Imagine I don't want to allow a person with the name "John".

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators

Comment: [EventListeners](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events.application-listener): https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/order/web/OrderControllerEventListener.java
[Annotated handlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler): https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes/blob/master/src/main/java/restvotes/web/eventHandler/PollEventHandler.java

Answer (score 0):

The typical thing to do would be to use Springs Bean Validation integration http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Which allows the validation of beans based on annotations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, what you want is for example, if there is a request to your API endpoint POST /users and the body contains the data for creating a new user in your database you would like for example to validate first if the username provided in the request is not already in use in your database, right?

If this is what you're looking for, you should use repository controllers instead of event handlers.

Continuing with my previous example, this is the controller handling the validation for a POST /users request validating that the username is not already in use and then if everything goes well, the new user will be saved otherwise, the client will receive an error message and the transaction won't be executed in the database.

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class UserController {
  private final UserRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  public UserController(UserRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/users")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {

    if (repository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) == null) {

      repository.save(user);

      Resource<User> resource;
      resource = new Resource<>(user);
      return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(resource, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } 

    else {

      ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(ErrorType.EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS);
      Resource<ErrorResponse> resource = new Resource<>(error);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the logic to check that a user with the same user name already exists belongs in the repository class (or another class in the domain layer), not in the RestController.